# Obtain a VideoFormat from a File

Tags: java, audio, video, jmf

I saw that I can retrieve information on an audio file in this way:

```
AudioFileFormat fileAudioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(mFile);
AudioFormat fileAudioFormat = fileAudioFileFormat.getFormat();
```

Is there a similar way to obtain a video format?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using JMF (obsolete, has not been updated in a looong time, so won't support most newer formats) or FMJ, or a variety of other 3rd party APIs.